# Find when Garbage Collector last ran in .NET

Tags: .net, collections, garbage-collection

Is there a way to figure out when the Garbage collector last ran in my program? Suppose I am running a computation-intensive program and am interested whether GC ran in the middle, how do I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my opinion, well designed programs (even computation-intensive ones) should not be interested in (or influenced by) when the GC ran.

Comment: @Jon Ok I can see the point for diagnostics. I was somehow thinking that the information was going to be used in the code itself. (Well, in a way even that could make sense).

Comment: Turn the problem around.  The GC behaves deterministically, it only ever runs when you allocate something.  So don't allocate when you calculate.  And if you do, there just isn't anything you can do about it.

Answer (score 2):

You could add logging code to the finalizer of an object that got collected.
This should only be done for diagnostic purposes; finalizers should not be used except for native resources.

You can also look at the [GC performance counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2tyfybc.aspx); for more details, see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/maoni/archive/2004/06/03/148029.aspx).

Comment: +1 good idea, but he doesn't know what the generation that it collect of course..

Answer (score 1):

Try CLR Profiler

I used it for .NET 3.5 (should be ok for 2.0-3.5)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650691.aspx

For .NET 4.0

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16273

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use Permon counters for this, specifically the `.Net CLR Memory` -> `% Time in GC` value:

> % Time in GC is the percentage of elapsed time that was spent in performing a garbage collection (GC) since the last GC cycle. This counter is usually an indicator of the work done by the Garbage Collector on behalf of the application to collect and compact memory. This counter is updated only at the end of every GC and the counter value reflects the last observed value; its not an average.

Its not exactly what you are asking for, but it looks to be a reasonable indication of the cost of garbage collection.  As a bonus, if the value of this counter changes then it means that at least one GC cycle has taken place.